# Error when diagonalising large matrices using anaconda scipy

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda, lapack

I have recently switched from using homebrew python on mac OS X to using anaconda, and I have started getting an error when diagonalising large(ish) matrices. Calling `scipy.linalg.eigvalsh(A)` with matrices above about 3000x3000 entries gives an error:

```
$HOME/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp.pyc in eigvalsh(a, b, lower, overwrite_a, overwrite_b, turbo, eigvals, type, check_finite)
    762                 overwrite_a=overwrite_a, overwrite_b=overwrite_b,
    763                 turbo=turbo, eigvals=eigvals, type=type,
--> 764                 check_finite=check_finite)
    765 
    766 

$HOME/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp.pyc in eigh(a, b, lower, eigvals_only, overwrite_a, overwrite_b, turbo, eigvals, type, check_finite)
    385         if eigvals is None:
    386             w, v, info = evr(a1, uplo=uplo, jobz=_job, range="A", il=1,
--> 387                              iu=a1.shape[0], overwrite_a=overwrite_a)
    388         else:
    389             (lo, hi) = eigvals

ValueError: On entry to ZHBRDB parameter number 12 had an illegal value
```

The final error message seems similar to this old scipy issue: [scipy/issues/5401](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5401), but the matrices I'm having problems with are much smaller.

Running `print np.__config__.show()` gives:

```
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['$HOME/anaconda2/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['$HOME/anaconda2/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['$HOME/anaconda2/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['$HOME/anaconda2/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['$HOME/anaconda2/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['$HOME/anaconda2/include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['$HOME/anaconda2/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['$HOME/anaconda2/include']
None
```

Comment: It's possible that Anaconda are using an old version of Lapack to support backwards compatibility. What version of SciPy are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version from running anaconda updates, '1.0.0'

Comment: You are probably using MKL now, while maybe something different before.

Comment: Yes I think that's right, I've added the output from np.__config__.show() to the question

Comment: This is known and I think a bug in MKL+conda https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8205

Comment: is there any fix, or anything I can do in the meantime to avoid the problem? they don't seem to discuss on the github bug report

Comment: I think this one needs to be reported to MKL people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, as it stands, an MKL bug which has been kindly reported by [@brd490](https://github.com/brd4790) as per the discussion in [SciPy issue 8205](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8205) and is [accepted by the Intel MKL team](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/753935)

Note that OpenBLAS-built SciPy does not have this issue. However, in the mean time, we have also noticed that the optimal workspace array sizes were not correct in the `scipy.linalg.eigh`.That is also going to be corrected once the decision over how to change the signature of the the underlying `?SYEVR`/`?HEEVR` wrappers.

As a bonus, probably one would be able to compute the eigenvalues selectively since originally these routines allow for it but were not exposed in `scipy.linalg.eigh`.